# Is it possible to print xdist gateway number to each line in stdout?

Tags: python, pytest, xdist

I am using logging module to print to stdout. 
It is hard to understand what message corresponds to worker when I run tests with pytest-xdist

Is it possible to print xdist gateway number to each line in stdout?

Example of log messages that I have now:

```
[02-22-2018_19.44.11] [DEBUG] [file.py:96] - Message
[02-22-2018_19.44.11] [DEBUG] [file2.py:16] - Message
[02-22-2018_19.44.12] [DEBUG] [file3.py:23] - Message
[02-22-2018_19.44.12] [DEBUG] [file4.py:30] - Message
```

Desired:

```
[02-22-2018_19.44.11] [gw1] [DEBUG] [file.py:96] - Message
[02-22-2018_19.44.11] [gw0] [DEBUG] [file2.py:16] - Message
[02-22-2018_19.44.12] [gw0] [DEBUG] [file3.py:23] - Message
[02-22-2018_19.44.12] [gw3] [DEBUG] [file4.py:30] - Message
```

or

```
gw1 [02-22-2018_19.44.11] [DEBUG] [file.py:96] - Message
gw0 [02-22-2018_19.44.11] [DEBUG] [file2.py:16] - Message
gw0 [02-22-2018_19.44.12] [DEBUG] [file3.py:23] - Message
gw3 [02-22-2018_19.44.12] [DEBUG] [file4.py:30] - Message
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the gateway id via the `config.slaveinput` attribute. Example:

```
def test_spam(pytestconfig):
    assert hasattr(pytestconfig, 'slaveinput')
    assert pytestconfig.slaveinput['slaveid'] == 'gw0'
```

The test will only pass when `xdist` is actually invoked, e.g. via `pytest -n1 test_spam.py`, otherwise the `slaveinput` attribute won't be set.

Comment: But I use log messages not only in tests. So how to get 'gw' from test I know, but how to set it globally for logging - I don't (is it possible)

Comment: So you don't know how to access the `config` outside of tests? `import pytest; config = pytest.config; logging.info(config.slaveinput['slaveid'])`.

Comment: @hoefling theres no such thing as pytest.config I am using 3.7.3

Comment: @Imran the answer is 2.5 years old; since then, `pytest.config` was deprecated and removed.

Comment: yes. Can't find anyway to access pytest config outside of the test

Comment: @Imran there's no way of accessing config on module level anymore. Move the code to a fixture or a hookimpl that has the access to config object.